# Where is the ability to hibernate exposed on Linux?

Tags: linux, slackware, hibernate

When I boot with a `resume=..` option to the kernel and an `initrd` built with a `-h` option, userland tools (say, `batti`) offer me the choice of hibernation; when I boot without them it does not.

Where is the fact that I have a system capable of hibernate/resume exposed for these tools to find that out? (This is on Slackware, in case this is init-specific.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is via the `/sys/power` interface.  The usual way to induce hibernation (used by various higher level tools) is to write to a couple of the fields there:

```
echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk
echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

I believe the first one sets the methodology and the second one triggers the change.<sup>1</sup> However, if you *read* from these nodes, you get a list of possibities:

```
> cat /sys/power/disk
platform [shutdown] reboot suspend

> cat /sys/power/state
freeze standby mem disk
```

Since `shutdown` and `disk` are available, the machine can be put into hibernation.

---

<sup>1 You can also set `platform` on `/sys/power/disk` to do the same thing via the system's ACPI hardware, presuming the driver works properly, and `echo mem > /sys/power/state` puts the machine into suspend (state saved to ram).</sup>

Comment: Cool, thanks. I've written to those files for years and never thought to read from them.